# How To Animate Line Renderer When Multiple Points Are Clicked in Unity

Tags: c, unity-game-engine, ienumerator

I have multiple points on screen and when a player clicks them in correct order, it should animate a line between them. If player clicks on points faster than the line appear animation can go, next line is animated only when previous one is finished. I followed these tutorials, but can't manage to blend them together:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3cs6ybxWdY&t=267s

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMM3BAick4I

---

[I currently have this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lv6DH.gif)

---

Code I'm using:

[SerializeField]
private float animationDuration = 3f;

```
private LineRenderer lineRenderer;

private Vector3[] linePoints;
private int pointsCount;


public Transform lastPoints;
public List<Transform> points = new List<Transform>();

private void Awake()
{
    lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
}
public void MakeLine(Transform finalPoint)
{
    if (lastPoints == null)
    {
        lastPoints = finalPoint;
        points.Add(lastPoints);
    }
    else
    {
        points.Add(finalPoint);
        lineRenderer.enabled = true;
        SetupLine();
    }
}

private void SetupLine()
{
    int pointLength = points.Count;
    lineRenderer.positionCount = pointLength;

    for (int i = 0; i < pointLength; i++)
    {
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(i, points[i].position);
    }
}
```

This one animates all points at once:

```
public IEnumerator AnimateLine()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < pointsCount - 1; i++)
    {
        float startTime = Time.time;

        Vector3 startPos = linePoints[i];
        Vector3 endPos = linePoints[i+1];

        Vector3 pos = startPos;
        while (pos != endPos)
        {
            float t = (Time.time - startTime) / animationDuration;
            pos = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, t);
            for (int j = i+1; j < pointsCount; j++)
            {
                lineRenderer.SetPosition(j, pos);
            }
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Calling on single mouse click:

```
private void CheckClickDownEvent()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        var selectedObject = RaycastObject();
        
        if(selectedObject != null)
        {
            OnObjectSelect?.Invoke(selectedObject);
        }
    }
}

private void HandlePointSelect(GameObject selectedPoint)
{
    if (spawner.points.IndexOf(selectedPoint) == 0)
    {
        selectedPoint.GetComponent<PointScript>().SelectPoint();
        spawner.points.Remove(selectedPoint);
        lineAnimator.MakeLine(selectedPoint.transform);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. How are you calling `AnimateLine` and `MakeLine`? Please show your code.

Comment: I'm only calling  MakeLine(). AnimateLine() is just another method for reference, but it would be called the same way.